# Search Folders in ColdFusion 9

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to create a search method to attach files on my outbound emails. I need to search inside a folder and find all the files that begin with a certain character and then attach them to the email. I just need a head start on how you could create such a search method so any pointers or links to references will be appreciated.

This is What I have so far but it does not seem to work correct when I use a path instead of `GetBaseTemplatePath()`

```
<cfscript>
  attributes.attachments = 2011093475839213;
</cfscript>

<cfset Directory = "E:\sites\Example.com\FileFolder\#attributes.attachments#"> 


<cfset CurrentDirectory=Directory>  
<cfset CurrentDirectory=ListDeleteAt(CurrentDirectory,ListLen(CurrentDirectory,"/\"),"/\")>  

<cfoutput>  
 <b>Current Directory:</b> #CurrentDirectory#  
    <br />  
</cfoutput>  

<cfdirectory action="list" directory="#CurrentDirectory#" name="result">  
<cfdump var="#result#">
```

When I change the code slightly by

```
<cfset CurrentDirectory=GetBaseTemplatePath()>
```

My code works and I get the list of all the files in my current directory. Do I have a mistake on my path that I cannot see?

This is my CFMAIL part which I do have an issue with.
When I dump my `#result#` query I get all the files inside the folder. Then I get this error:

```
The resource 2011093475839213.pdf was not found.

The root cause was: ''.
```

I do receive an email despite the error, just not the attached files.

```
<!--- Email Test --->
<CFMAIL FROM="user1@example.com" TO="user2@example.com"  SUBJECT="Test" type="HTML">
<P> This is the attachment test</P>
<p> For this test to be successful, we need to receive some file attachments with this email</p>

    <cfloop query="result">

        <cfmailparam file="#result.name#" disposition="attachment">

    </cfloop>


</cfmail>
<!--- Email Test Ends --->
```

Comment: What happens if you do `<cfdump var=#DirectoryExists(CurrentDirectory)# />` ?

Also, you don't need that `ListDeleteAt` stuff - use [`getDirectoryFromPath`](http://cfdocs.org/getdirectoryfrompath)

Comment: I manage to go around it with DirectoryExists and I did have an error to my path after all. I will try to use the getDirectoryFromPath because I am having some issues when there is a subdirectory involved

Comment: I am getting an error on my `cfmailparam` tag that `The resource 2011093475839213.pdf was not found.

The root cause was: ''.` 
  
I am dumping the query and that file does exist. I don't know why is giving me the error.

Comment: You're not specifying the directory. Use `#result.directory#/#result.name#`

Comment: @PeterBoughton yes that what the error was. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="#myDirectory#" name="myDir">

<cfmail subject="My Subject" to="yourAddress" from="myAddress">
  My Message
  <cfsilent>
    <cfloop query="myDir">
      <cfif Left(myDir.name,1) eq "Z">
        <cfmailparam file="#myDirectory & myDir.name#">
      </cfif>
    </cfloop>
  </cfsilent>
</cfmail>
```

Comment: To check the first character, do `left(mydir.name,1) EQ 'Z'` instead - although in this case you don't even need that, since you can do `filter="Z*"` on the cfdirectory tag.

Answer (score 2):

The cfdirectory tag will allow you to search through folder(s) with a specific pattern. Using the query it returns, you can loop over it and attach all the files you need to the email.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f99.html

Comment: Thanks for the link I will try it and let you know.